# Overactive Infopath form validation

Tags: 2013, infopath, validation

I have a date cell set to require entry if there is an action item entered in another cell (using the rule on the date cell if Action is not blank and Date is blank) which works normally if text is entered

The problem I am seeing is that if I click into the Action text field and then click out of it without entering any text the validation error still occurs even though there is no text in Action so there is no reason to need a date.

This is happening with InfoPath 2013 in Chrome (but not IE or the preview in InfoPath) Sharepoint 2013

Additionally, if I fill out a required cell, but then remove the text the cell will not require text anymore.